# SQL ODBC to Intersystems Cache - lost Cache master user and password

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems

Is there any way to access the Cache database data tables via SQL ODBC connection when the
Intersystems Cache database admin username and password has been lost?

Answer (score 4):

Not via ODBC. You should change password from Caché directly.
If you don't know any admin passwords to access Caché you can use EmergencyId (http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20131/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCAS_secmgmt#GCAS_secmgmt_emerg)

Comment: This is the correct answer. To add to it, once you've started in emergency mode you should login, change to the %SYS namespace and run the SECURITY routine to edit a user which can be used to enter the portal with the "%All" privilege.